# Can I truncate or "zoom-in" on a section of a pyplot figure before calling show, to avoid exceeding the complexity limit?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I don't have a specific code example because this is something I do a lot in an interactive session, so I'm sort of looking for a more general answer to my question.

So say I want to look at two large datasets to check of they are synchronized:

```
plt.plot(Big_List_X)
plt.plot(list_Y_to_X_index, Big_List_Y)
plot.show()
```

Where list_Y_to_X_index is a list that links  Big_List_Y to Big_List_X. This causes a rendering complexity error.

This is what my workaround looks like:

```
plt.plot(Big_List_X[0::100])
plt.plot(list_Y_to_X_index[0::100], Big_List_Y)
plot.show()
```

In this case I loose precession and can't really see what's happening up close. 
Alternatively:

```
plt.plot(Big_List_X[some_lower_boundry:some_upper_boundry])
plt.plot(list_Y_to_X_index[some_lower_boundry:some_upper_boundry], Big_List_Y)
plot.show()
```

This only works if I have some sort of index linking one list to the other. And I feel like it's a bit inelegant. Regardless of what I do, I still end up playing a guessing game do see how much data I can look a in a window without hitting the limit.

Is there anything I can do like:

```
plt.show(range = [some_lower_bound, some_upper_bound])
```

And am I stuck playing the guessing game of how many points I can see at once?

Comment: I found my solution using plt.xlim()

    plt.plot(Big_List_X)
    plt.plot(list_Y_to_X_index, Big_List_Y)
    plt.xlim(some_lower_bound, some_upper_bound)
    plot.show()

Now I can view a portion of my plot with out truncating the data I pass in.

Comment: Welcome to [SO], @nick! Please post your comment as an answer (you can answer your own question after some time limit), and then select it as the "best" answer using the checkmark.